# how to use single page call in openx 2.8.5

Tags: openx

i need to repeat same zone multiple times in the same page.im using openx 2.8.5 but single page call is not working. will somebody please tell me how to use single page call in openx 2.8.5

Answer (score 0):

You can generate single page invocation tags via "Website Level". To show same zone just copy and place that zone code multiple times on same page, but need to do some changes on code.

For example : zone id is : 7 means then paste this code multiple times.

[image]

Detailed usage and tips for single page invocation tags, find here: http://www.adserveropenx.com/single-page-call-invocation-code
http://www.reviveadserverplugin.com/blog/single-page-call-invocation-code

Answer (score 0):

We have examined revive 2.8.5 with single page call and it was working fine.
Sample ad tag format:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/openx2.8.5/www/delivery/spcjs.php?id=1'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[/* [id1] www.dreamajax.com - Default */OA_show(1);// ]]> --></script>
<noscript><a target='_blank' href='http://localhost/openx2.8.5/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a09a326'><img border='0' alt='' src='http://localhost/openx-2.8.5/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=1&amp;n=a09a326' /></a></noscript>

<script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[/* [id1] www.dreamajax.com Default */OA_show(1);// ]]> --></script>
<noscript><a target='_blank' href='http://localhost/openx2.8.5/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a09a326'><img border='0' alt='' src='http://localhost/openx-2.8.5/www/delivery/avw.php zoneid=1&amp;n=a09a326' /></a></noscript>

<script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[/* [id1] www.dreamajax.com - Default */OA_show(1);
// ]]> --></script>
<noscript><a target='_blank' href='http://localhost/openx-2.8.5/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a09a326'><img border='0' alt='' src='http://localhost/openx-2.8.5/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=1&amp;n=a09a326' /></a></noscript>
```